# code inside async function executes before the code that follows it

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm currently exploring the concept of async/await in javascript.I know that async function returns a promise which supposed to resolve in a future time and it doesn't block the natural execution of code.Here I have a code which i wrote to test the async execution of javascript.

```
console.log("1")
async function asyncFunc(){
  for(i=0;i<10000000;i++){
  }
  console.log("3")
}
asyncFunc().then(()=>{console.log('4')});
console.log("2");
```

I except the code will be executed in the following fashion:

> first console.log() prints 1
>
> secondly async function is called. As async code is non blocking,last console.log() will execute and thus prints 2 in the console.
>
> After that console.log() inside async function will be executed and will print 3 in console.
>
> lastly the promise will be resolved and console.log() inside `then` will be executed and prints 4.
>
> so expected output : 1,2,3,4
>
> but in reality I get output as 1,3,2,4.

why it behaves like this and not the way I expected

Comment: The aync keyword doesn't actually make the code in the function async unfortunately.

Comment: if you want to force the function to run asynchronously, then add `await Promise.resolve()` as first line of the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function doesn't return a promise until it has finished running (unless you `await` another promise inside it).

The loop runs (blocking everything), then `console.log("3")` is evaluated, then it returns a promise.

The calling function continues to run (logging 2).

Finally, the event loop is freed up and the function passed to `then` is called.

Marking a function as async doesn't turn synchronous code inside it into asynchronous code.

Comment: declaring it async i expect it to be async.if it still blocks then what's the point ?

Comment: @AL-zami — It provides nicer syntax for when you are dealing with code which is async (since you can use syntax that deals in returns instead of callbacks).

Comment: your last comment made it even more difficult to grasp unfortunately :(

Comment: Look at the MDN page for async. It has examples.

Comment: Async means that it is ENABLED to run as async, but doesn't make it async. 'await' inside the async function is what makes it async. There are no 'await' inside asyncFunc, so it's not really async

Answer (score 2):

Late answer here, and Quentin is exactly right, but it's helpful sometimes to diagram these things. Let's look at really simple `async` function:

```
async function foo() {
    console.log("a");
    await something();
    console.log("b");
    return 42;
}
```

That function has two parts:

- A synchronous part: Everything up to (but not including) the first `await` or `return` (or if it just ends). So in the above, that's the `console.log("a");` and the call to `something` (but not the bit waiting for its result).
- An asynchronous part: Anything following that first `await`.

If we were to rewrite that function with explicit promises, it would look something like this *(hand-waving away details)*:

```
function foo() {
    console.log("a");
    return something().then(() => {
        console.log("b");
        return 42;
    });
}
```

So looking at your function:

```
async function asyncFunc(){
  for(i=0;i<10000000;i++){
  }
  console.log("3")
}
```

...we can see that **all** of the code in the function is in its initial synchronous part, and the promise it returns will be resolved with `undefined`.

So **why** do `async` functions have a synchronous part? For the same reason the executor function you pass into `new Promise` runs synchronously: So it can *start* its work right away.

Suppose we wanted to do an `async` wrapper around `fetch` where we expect a JSON response:

```
async function fetchJSON(...args) {
    const response = fetch(...args);
    return response.json();
};
```

If that didn't have a synchronous part (the call to `fetch(...args)`), it would never do anything and its promise would never be settled.